# How to speed up HAVING which uses a LIKE %...%

Tags: mysql, sql, having

We have a query taking 30 seconds. When we remove this HAVING clause, it takes 1 second:

```
HAVING (group_concat(DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY 
service.service ASC SEPARATOR ",") like "%translation%")
ORDER by fqa_value DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

The field service.service is an ENUM with one of the items "translation".

Is there a more efficient way to construct this HAVING without building a comma-separated string and then searching in it as text, something like this:

```
HAVING ("translation" IN (DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service))
ORDER by fqa_value DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: can you give full sql.

Comment: Any improvements if you remove distinct and/or order by?

Comment: I suspect `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` are how the aggregate is called in the `SELECT`, and what's used in the `HAVING` clause should be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, when I removed the "ORDER by fqa_value DESC", the speed where from 30 seconds to 0.001 seconds.

Comment: Another thing do you have an index on fqa_value?If you dont care about which 10 records do you get,yes the ORDER BY can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there is a logical error in this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING (group_concat(DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service ASC SEPARATOR ",") like "%translation%")
```

This will match things like `atranslation`, `btranslation`, etc. because you are not explicitly matching a starting comma. You want something more like this (the parentheses around the clause are superfluous):

```
HAVING CONCAT(',', group_concat(DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service ASC SEPARATOR ","), ',') like "%,translation,%"
```

or this:

```
HAVING 'translation' REGEXP CONCAT('^(', group_concat(DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service ASC SEPARATOR '|'), ')$')
```

However, I don't think either of those will significantly help your performance. Instead, what you might do is the following:

```
SELECT mykeycolumn, fqa_value, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service ASC SEPARATOR ",")
  FROM service s1
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM service s2
                 WHERE s2.mykeycolumn = s1.mykeycolumn
                   AND s2.service = 'translation' )
 ORDER BY fqa_value DESC
 LIMIT 0,10;
```

where `mykeycolumn` is your primary key column or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since your LIKE starts with a wildcard you're going to have to change something fundamentally about your approach. There's no way for MySQL to index the data when you're doing full text search.

If you can alter the table:

Split the enum into bool-columns (one for each possible enum value) and index those. That's the only way you're going to get faster than O(n).

Comment: You're missing the fact that this is a `HAVING` clause I think? Even if it was `HAVING indexedcolumn  = 1 `, it would still ignore your index, as it is not a `WHERE`, so it is run afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

"translation" IN (DISTINCT service.service ORDER BY service.service)
"DISTINCT" and " ORDER BY" are not relavent and should be discarded.

I did something similar to what you are trying but I created an additional field and stuck all searchable fields in it, then search that field.

You would have to go back and change (add to)  your tables, write a trigger, but it should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

You may find that you get better performance if you remove the HAVING clause, and instead add *another* join (under another alias) to the Services table with the existing join criteria, with the additional criterion `service = "translation"` .